# How to switch the order of text in a line?

Tags: python, file, line

I have a text file with lines going like this: `text1:numbers:text2`. How do I separate these so that I can output for example `text1:text2:numbers` to another file?

```
file1=open("textfile.txt","r")

file2=open("textfile2.txt","w") 

while True:

    line=file1.readline()

    a=line.split(":")

    if line=="":break
```

Comment: How indeed. What have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: What are the examples of "text1" and "text2"?

Comment: posted it above.

Comment: We need a specific error, problem or behavior to identify an adequate answer. Currently flagged for closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can assign each text part to a variable in your `split`, then write out in the separate order.

```
with open("textfile.txt") as f1, open("textfile2.txt", "w") as f2:
    for line in f1:
        text1, numbers, text2 = line.split(":")
        # N.B. this will fail if there are more *or* less than 3 parts to line.split(":")
        # on any line of the file. Ensure that there is not, or wrap this in a
        # try/except block and handle appropriately.

        f2.write("{}:{}:{}\n".format(text1, text2, numbers))
        # or f2.write(':'.join([text1, text2, numbers, "\n"]))
        # or f2.write(text1 + ":" + text2 + ":" + numbers + "\n")
        # or any other way to assemble the text you want.

        # my favorite in Py3.6+ is an f-string
        # f2.write(f"{text1}:{text2}:{numbers}\n")
```

Note that I'm also using a context manager to open the files, and iterating over the file objects directly rather than an infinite loop until `readline` returns nothing. You should prefer context managers over explicit `open` and `close` statements because it ensures the file object/s close after exiting from the block, even if that exit isn't clean (exceptions are thrown and handled or etc). Iterating over the file object instead of reading a line at a time in an infinite loop is just idiomatically nicer-looking.